# Sharepoint Impersonation Workflow Modified By Value in custom list

Tags: workflow, custom-list, impersonation, workflow-app-step

I have a custom workflow for submitting proposals. This was designed by my predecessor as a long single step.

1. A user creates a proposal which is added to a custom list and the workflow begins.
2. The workflow sends an email to the right manager who then reviews and approves/denies the workflow.
3. If approved it moves up to the next manager up the chain.

The "modified by" value would update with each manager that approved the workflow to signify where in the process the proposal is.

This worked fine until we started having users with less permissions submit proposals, which cause the workflow to fail when trying to send an email without send permissions.

Without modifying anything in the workflow I turned the single step into an impersonation step so that these users could submit new proposals. This however causes the "modified by" value to appear always as the account which published the workflow.

My question is how would I go about retaining the modified by field based on the current manager approved, while allowing users to submit proposals without giving them more permissions?

Can I cut up the workflow into multiple steps some regular some impersonation without it breaking? or would it be easier to just make a new field that acts like the "modified by" field?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use multiple app step blocks for particular actions in workflow. But I will suggest to make new field which will act like "modified by" and update this field every time manager approves/denies the task.